# General linear group analogs

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

The Wikipedia pages for $E_6$ and $E_7$ list three series of groups notated as each of $E_6(q)$, $^2E_6(q)$, and $E_7(q)$:

- The simple form, analogous to $\operatorname{PSL}_n(q)$
- The adjoint form, analogous to $\operatorname{PGL}_n(q)$
- The universal form, analogous to $\operatorname{SL}_n(q)$

Is there a fourth series analogous to $\operatorname{GL}_n(q)$?

Comment: But the general linear group is not semisimple, so it is not like the others.

Comment: Yet it still has analogs for the classical group families in the form of the general unitary groups, general symplectic groups, and pin groups.